# Back4app uploading object issue

Tags: python, python-requests, parse-server, back4app

I'm trying to create an object through `back4app` for class `sound`

the issue which am having that am unable to upload the file.

code used:

```
import requests

headers = {
    "X-Parse-Application-Id": "hidden",
    "X-Parse-REST-API-Key": "hidden",
}


data = {
    "audio": {
        "__type": open("a.mp3", 'rb'),
        "name": "a.mp3"

    },
    "displayText": "test"
}


def main(url):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        req.headers.update(headers)
        r = req.post(url, data=data)
        print(r.text)


main("https://parseapi.back4app.com/classes/sounds")
```

Output:

```
{"code":111,"error":"schema mismatch for sounds.audio; expected File but got Array"}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You first need to upload the file:

```js
import json,httplib
connection = httplib.HTTPSConnection('parseapi.back4app.com', 443)
connection.connect()
connection.request('POST', '/files/a.mp3', open('a.mp3', 'rb').read(), {
       "X-Parse-Application-Id": "${APPLICATION_ID}",
       "X-Parse-REST-API-Key": "${REST_API_KEY}",
       "Content-Type": "audio/mpeg"
     })
result = json.loads(connection.getresponse().read())
```

Then create the object:

```js
connection.request('POST', '/classes/sounds', json.dumps({
       "displayText": "test",
       "audio": {
         "name": result["name"],
         "url:": result["url"],
         "__type": "File"
       }
     }), {
       "X-Parse-Application-Id": "${APPLICATION_ID}",
       "X-Parse-REST-API-Key": "${REST_API_KEY}",
       "Content-Type": "application/json"
     })
connection.getresponse().read()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for that. i were trying to reach you via the support email. i just wondering why you did not support Python yet. i was just going to use [ParsePy](https://github.com/milesrichardson/ParsePy). now i got the point. thanks once again

Comment: i just tried your solution now. check [online](https://repl.it/@AmericanY/Back4App#main.py) but looks like it's not valid.

Comment: Could you please try with the exactly coded that I posted above? I've just tried and it is working pretty fine. I am using `httplib` instead of `http.client`. `http.client` should work as well but I believe that the request needs to be modified accordingly.